# How to show custom text (placeholder) in KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to show "-select date-" placeHolder in datepicker if no date defined. Is that possible?

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-inline"
        disablePast
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a placeholder in the form of the `placeholder` prop.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
        placeholder='-select date-'
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-inline"
        disablePast
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Check out the example on the [official documentation page](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

OK. the solution is to add labelFunc prop

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-inline"
        labelFunc={() => selectedDate || '- Select date -'}
        disablePast
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

or even better (assuming default date value == null):

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-inline"
        emptyLabel="- Select Date -"
        disablePast
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can**. don't get overwhelmed with ***null*** value and stuffs, this is one of many appropriate option you can do.

**Try this out:**

```
//You need all of these imports (a must)
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import Moment from 'moment';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, KeyboardDatePicker  } from "@material-ui/pickers";

//you need this too (a must)
const [selectDate, handleChangeSelectDate] = useState(null);

//Finally this is final thing you need
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
   <KeyboardDatePicker
      id="date-picker-inline"
      autoOk
      placeholder='-select date-'
      inputStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
      variant="inline"
      inputVariant="outlined"
      format="MMM/dd/yyyy" //Can use MM if you want to show only number of month
      value={selectDate? moment(selectDate) : null}
      InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }} //just use to put calendar icon on start or left position - remove it if you want it on end of the box or right hand side
      onChange={date => handleChangeSelectDate(date)}
   />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: A key point here is that the default value must be `null` rather than `undefined` - if it is `undefined` and you provide an `initialFocusedDate`, that initial date will show up instead of the placeholder.